# Bootstrap toggle also empty certain element(s) using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button when click toggles (AddFilters) as such:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info expand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".AddFilters">Show Attribute Filters</button>
```

When the user clicks on the button, I also wanted to hide an element on the page:

I need to do the following on click of the button (jquery code):

```
$('[id*=ptDescr]').empty();
```

I am not sure how to incorporate this so it toggles and also does the following:

```
$('[id*=ptDescr]').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap collapse triggers events that can be used to do additional things. In this case you want to empty an element on collapse so the code would be:
(give your button an ID or a class like id="magicButton")

```
$('#magicButton').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('[id*=ptDescr]').empty();
});
```

By the way $('#ptDescr').empty(); should do the trick.

[Bootstrap 3 Collapse Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse)